# How to change the values of instance attributes in a loop

Tags: python, class, dictionary, for-loop

I have a work implantation of python which has some inbuilt dialog boxes so I cannot share the original code here. The problem I have is I want to update the values of some instance attributes. I made a dictionary from zipping 2 lists together so that in a for loop I could mention to the user the string that they need to see for what they are updating(the dictionary key), and the instance attribute I want to change is the value of in the dictionary. But all its doing is changing the dictionary value, not the instance attribute value.

The dialog box will ask users "do you want to change {x relayed name} in a json file?". The value associated with that name in the dictionary is the instance attribute to be updated.

So I don't know if it can be done. Anyone got any ideas if it can?

Updated question after good comments made it clear the question was miswritten.

**Code**

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10.0
        self.y = 20.0

    def get_user_input(self):
        usr_ret = input("input a number :")
        return usr_ret


if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = MyClass()
    print(m.x)
    list_a = ["x_related_name", "y_related_name"]
    list_b = [m.x, m.y]
    mydict = dict(zip(list_a, list_b))
    for k, v in mydict.items():
        print(k, " : ", v)

    # update the class attribute value
    for k, v in mydict.items():

    
    #Can I update the class attributes x and y in a loop?
```

Comment: You can assign, modify, do whatever you like with m.x and m.y although implementing functions within the class (getters, setters etc) is better style

Comment: There are no class attributes anywhere in this question. As with the instance attributes you seem to be referring to, why loop at all? You have named keys in your dict that you can access directly. The whole point of the dict and the loop does not become obvious from the snippet you show here.

Comment: @BrutusForcus: "class (getters, setters etc) is better style" is not true for Python.

Comment: I assume you want to change class *instance* attributes, not class attributes. In this case the instance is `m`, so you would need to assign new value to the instance's `m.x` and `m.y` values to change them.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect the instance attributes instead of class attributes, apologies for the confusion, im self taught and still learning.

Comment: When I am working out a method I usually do it in the space under the "if __name__ ... once it works I make it a proper method and move it into the class

Comment: What do you want to happen in the loop at the end? i.e. what values do you want to assign the instance attributes from `k` and `v`? Please update your question to indicate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you want `getattr` and `setattr`? In the following, I simplified the example, as I can't find where user inputs are used in your example.

`getattr` gets the attribute value according to the attribute name, and `setattr` sets a value to a specified attribute (again, based on its name). So you just need to store the attribute names in a list of strings, and the loop over the list as needed.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10.0
        self.y = 20.0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = MyClass()
    attrs = ['x', 'y']
    for a in attrs:
        print(f"{a}: {getattr(m, a)}")
    set_as = [42, 2021]
    for a, v in zip(attrs, set_as):
        setattr(m, a, v)
    for a in attrs:
        print(f"{a}: {getattr(m, a)}")
```

Comment: I can see that works, will try and adapt it to my problem. First time I have seen getattr and setattr.